# Gradle build null console object

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to get my gradle builds to prompt at the console for a password using examples from stack overflow

When I have a statment such as:

```
def password = System.console().readLine("Enter keystore password ")
```

When I run I get the error

```
Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object
```

It seems console is coming out as `null`. What I've read this requires java 6 which if I go to a command prompt and type `java -version` I'm running Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07).

This issue is being tracked in Gradle's Github repo: [Can't use System.console() with the Gradle Daemon](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1251).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, the reason why this didn't work was silly, but just in case anyone else comes across it I thought I'd post.

I was running the task through android studio and didn't realise that the console object would always be null. When running from the command line the "command" object isn't null and it works ok.

Comment: Did you find a workaround to make this work when running from both places?

Comment: In my case the object is null even running through the terminal. I'm not trying to run via AS.

Answer (score 47):

For some reason, running gradle in daemon mode causes a null console object. If you specify the appropriate command line flag,

`./gradlew assembleRelease --no-daemon`

it'll work.

Comment: Lol, this worked on a project, but not the other one.

Comment: Does not work using gradle 4.2 > Cannot invoke method readPassword() on null object

Comment: "Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project "

Answer (score 22):

I found a solution here at https://www.timroes.de/2014/01/19/using-password-prompts-with-gradle-build-files and slightly modified it. Nevertheless, all credits go to Tim Roes!

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
if(taskGraph.hasTask(':app:assembleRelease')) {
    def storePass = ''
    def keyPass = ''
    if(System.console() == null) {
        new SwingBuilder().edt {
            dialog(modal: true, title: 'Enter password', alwaysOnTop: true, resizable: false, locationRelativeTo: null, pack: true, show: true) {
                vbox { // Put everything below each other
                    label(text: "Please enter store passphrase:")
                    def input1 = passwordField()
                    label(text: "Please enter key passphrase:")
                    def input2 = passwordField()
                    button(defaultButton: true, text: 'OK', actionPerformed: {
                        storePass = input1.password;
                        keyPass = input2.password;
                        dispose();
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        storePass = System.console().readPassword("\nPlease enter store passphrase: ")
        keyPass = System.console().readPassword("\nPlease enter key passphrase: ")
    }

    if(storePass.size() <= 0 || keyPass.size() <= 0) {
        throw new InvalidUserDataException("You must enter the passwords to proceed.")
    }

    storePass = new String(storePass)
    keyPass = new String(keyPass)

    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePass
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPass
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the some gradle file, you have the configuration for the release signing defined.

```
android {
...
signingConfigs {
    ...
    release {
        storeFile file(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\android-key")
        storePassword ''
        keyAlias "standard"
        keyPassword ''
    }
}

...
}
```

(Don't forget to `import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder`.)

Regarding the second part, you may also have a look at [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

Comment: Tim Roes solution for this is great

Comment: very nice production-ready modification, thank you. don't forget to `import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder`

Comment: AS now shows an error about `import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder`. Fortunately it will still do a debug build, and the command line gradlew can still import groovy. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/43423331/1682419

Comment: wow, be easy, just use: def pass = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password please:")

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get a ```Failed to create component for 'dialog' reason: java.awt.HeadlessException
> java.awt.HeadlessException (no error message)
```

Answer (score 13):

Executing `System.getConsole()` from *Gradle* when `org.gradle.daemon` property is `true`, or when it's executed from an IDE like *IntelliJ* or *Android Studio* it returns `null`. So for example do `System.console().readLine()` becomes not possible.

Furthermore starting from [*Gradle 3.0* `gradle.daemon` is turned on by default](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/release-notes.html#improved-gradle-daemon,-now-enabled-by-default).

Then instead of a workaround to use `System.getConsole()` I purpose an alternative, use `ant.input` like so:

```
task avoidNullOnConsole << {
    ant.input(message: 'Enter keystore password:', addproperty: 'userInputPassword', defaultValue : '1234')
    def password = ant.properties.userInputPassword
}
```

In this case `ant.input` shows the `message` and adds the user input in `ant.properties` using as a property name the value defined in `addProperty`. If there is no user input then the value defined in `default` attribute is used.

Once executed you can get the user input using `ant.properties.yourProperty` or `ant.properties['yourProperty']`.

You can check the rest of the [`ant.input` attributes here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html).

**Note:** If you want to use `ant.input` multiple times take in account that you cannot override and existing property so `addProperty` attribute must be different for each one.

Comment: That works well, is there a way to hide what the user is typing?

Comment: If you're using `ant.version > 1.8` seems that adding `handler(type:'secure')` to the `ant.input` must works... I check using `<input message="Enter some user input data?" addproperty="userInput" defaultValue="nothing"><handler type="secure"/></input>` in a `build.xml` and works well, however in `build.gradle` the equivalent `ant.input(message: 'Enter some user input data?', addproperty: 'userInput', defaultValue : 'nothing'){
    handler(type: 'secure')
  }` not hides the user input :(

Answer (score 9):

To workaround this problem I used the standard input stream as next:

```
println "Enter keystore password"
def password = System.in.newReader().readLine()
```

Comment: Works. Howeber, how to read password? `readPassword()` is function of `Console` class.

Comment: @galcyurio, what does `readPassword()` give you that `readLine()` doesn't? Does it just hide input?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this blog post (https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/).

It describes multiple ways to handle signing configs and one of them is exactly your question regarding console input for the password.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute your script also with:

-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution to this is to check the console object for null:

```
def password = null
def console = System.console()
if (console != null) {
    password = console.readLine("Enter keystore password: ")
}
```

Android Studio no longer complaints about the `null object`.

To hide typed chars use `readPassword()` instead of `readLine()`:

```
password = new String(console.readPassword("\nEnter key password: "))
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of not having the console. You want to input the password through a command line or console. Now you will have the problem of a null password.

Answer (score 2):

create a simple function to request a password:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane

def askPass() {
  def msg = 'Enter keystore password'
  if (System.console() != null) {
    return System.console().readLine(msg)
  } else {
    return javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(msg)
  }
}
```

or if you want Y/n answer:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane

def ask(msg) {
  if (System.console() != null) {
    return System.console().readLine(msg + ' [y/n]') == 'y'
  } else {
    def res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, msg, "Confirm operation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)
    return res == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION
  }
}

// usage:

task run() {
  doFirst {
    if (file('out.txt').exists() && !ask('overwrite output?')) {
      System.exit(2)
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the official solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187990/103412

Answer (score -2):

```
password System.console() != null ? System.console().readLine("\ password: ") : ""
```

Comment: Not setting the password at all does not help.