# Gradlew on Windows - System.console() is null

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

#### I want to use `System.console()` in my `build.gradle` to let the user enters the password for the keystore.

But then i execute

```
gradlew assembleRelease --no-daemon
```

i always get

```
Cannot invoke method readPassword() on null object
```

How can i request user input for gradlew on windows?

***I searched a lot on google and stack overflow but nothing works.***

Comment: I have the same issue on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

There are some known issues with using `System.console()` in Gradle. If `--no-daemon` doesn't help (it helps to some extent on my Mac), there is likely nothing you can do to make it work (except to submit a pull request to the Gradle project that fixes the problem). One way to work around the console input issues is to pop up a Swing dialog instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use -P command line option of gradle to help the signing. In your build.gradle, add singingConfigs like this:

```
signingConfigs {
      release {
          storeFile file("path/to/your/keystore")
          storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
          keyAlias "your.key.alias"
          keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
      }
   }
```

Then call gradle build like this:

> gradle -PRELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=******* -PRELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=****** build
>   You can use -P to set storeFile and keyAlias if you prefer.

This is basically Destil's solution but with the command line options.

For more details on gradle properties, check the gradle user guide.

Answer (score -1):

Then don't use `gradlew` .  Use  `gradle` instead.  Gradlew  runs in the back ground, which is not interactable and therefore how would you enter input that wants to be read?

Comment: On windows there is only a gradlew.bat. So this does not work.

Comment: Thats NOT true.  I use gradle all the time and gradle.bat is, in fact, included in the Gradle distro.  Fix your path or download Gradle again and put it in your path.

Comment: I got the gradlew from the android studio project. I download the gradle distro now and see if it works. Thanks for your friendly help.