# Log console output from a gradle script to file

Tags: unix, gradle

I want to log all console output from my gradle script to log file:

```
gradle test 2>&1 | tee -a gradle.log
```

But my gradle script prompts param from user:

```
task test << {
        System.console().readLine("Enter:").toString()
}
```

As a result, I have a NullPointerException:

```
Execution failed for task ':test'. Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object
```

May be somebody know a solution or workaround for this situation?

Comment: Is this at all related to logging the console output? From what I remember, `System.console()` may not be available in a Gradle build script, at least not when using the Gradle daemon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle build null console object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487576/gradle-build-null-console-object)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
yes <desired input> | gradle test 2>&1 | tee -a gradle.log
```

`yes` just repeditively echos whatever it's argument is to stdout