# `System.console()` returns `null` if executed from `gradle run`

Tags: java, gradle, console

I have this simple Java program:

```
package me.fornever.javaterminal;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Console: " + System.console());
    }
}
```

And this simple `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'me.fornever.javaterminal.Main'
```

When I'm executing it using `gradle --no-daemon run`, I get the following output:

```
Console: null
```

If I execute it from the terminal through `gradle jar; java -cp '.\build\libs\java-terminal.jar' me.fornever.javaterminal.Main`, I get the following:

```
Console: java.io.Console@3d4eac69
```

I am aware that `System.console()` may return `null` when the parent process uses stdout redirection. Is there some Gradle option to disable the redirection and make the console fully available for my program?

I am developing a terminal library for Java, so I want to run my tests and executables without Gradle intervention in stdin/stdout/stderr.

Please note that `System.console()` being `null` is not the only issue but the most obvious one. In reality I want to access WinAPI `WriteConsoleW` function from the program executed by `gradle run`, and I'm unable to use this function due to the same reasons `System.console()` being `null`. So I *really* need to disable output redirection in Gradle if this option is available.

Also please note that the question is different from [Gradle build null console object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487576/gradle-build-null-console-object) because that question asks how to use `System.console()` inside of a Gradle script and not in the Java program invoked by `gradle run`; I believe they're working differently in that matter, because neither of the answers are working or applicable to my case.

Comment: How can you *test* a program that uses `console()`? You can't send it test input and you can't verify the output, so what are you testing?

Comment: @Andreas first of all I test if it's working at all and not throwing any exceptions. And the second option is to use some platform-dependent API like win32 `ReadConsoleOutput` or a wrapper such as `winpty`. I am writing a wrapper library for Windows console, so it's okay to use platform-dependent solutions.

Comment: So when you did a web search, what did you find? Did you find this duplicate question?

Comment: Nope, the linked answer doesn't work for me. I specially mentioned that I'm running `gradle --no-daemon run` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, the linked question is about getting `System.console()` inside of a Gradle script, and not in the Java program invoked by `gradle run`. So I still think that my question is different from the linked one. I've added this information to my question.

Comment: I have the same issue. I readed somewhere that including     `standardInput = System.in` in run task will make it work, but it didn't work for me. Anyway, some reported that this worked for them.

Comment: Starting from JDK22, `System.console()` will not return null in these cases: https://inside.java/2023/07/31/quality-heads-up/

Answer (score 4):

In order for `java.io.Console` to be available, the child processes' stdin and stdout have to point to a Linux/macOS/Unix terminal or a Windows console. The easiest way to arrange that is to inherit the stdin and stdout from a parent process already set up that way. However, there is a known limitation of Gradle ([GRADLE-3292](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3292)) that the `JavaExec` task type does not support making the child process inherit the input/output streams of the parent process.

If the Gradle `JavaExec` task type was enhanced to support stdin/stdout inheritance, then this could be made to work for `gradle --no-daemon run`.

Getting it to work with the Gradle daemon would be far more complex, and likely involve platform-specific code to manipulate pseudoterminals or call the Windows console API.