# Running an application which uses java.io.Console API from Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, terminal, tui

Consider I have a *Java* (or *Kotlin*, doesn't really matter) application which uses `java.io.Console` API, or any other API which manipulates the terminal state (e.g.: [`net.rubygrapefruit:native-platform`](https://github.com/adammurdoch/native-platform)):

```
System.out.println(format("Console is %s.", System.console()));

final Terminals terminals = Native.get(Terminals.class);
final Output out = Stdout;
if (terminals.isTerminal(out)) {
    final TerminalOutput stdout = terminals.getTerminal(out);
    stdout.bold();
    System.out.println("bold text");
    stdout.foreground(Color.Magenta);
    System.out.println("Magenta");
    stdout.reset();

    final Prompter prompter = new Prompter(terminals);
    prompter.askYesNo("Prompt", true);
    prompter.enterText("Text", "default text");
    prompter.enterPassword("Password");
    prompter.select("Select", asList("foo", "bar", "baz"), 1);
} else {
    System.out.println(format("%s is not a terminal.", out));
}
```

The above code would run just fine when launched by [Maven Exec plug-in](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), but with *Gradle* (since *Gradle* tries to make **its own** output look pretty, with all those bells, whistles and progress bars) the code just prints:

```
$ gradle --console=plain run
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :run
Console is null.
Stdout is not a terminal.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Configuring the `run` task as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172137) and [here](https://medium.com/@mglover/running-a-command-line-app-from-gradle-62f88b3f14c2):

```kotlin
private val run: JavaExec by tasks
run.apply {
    standardInput = System.`in`
    standardOutput = System.out
    errorOutput = System.err
}
```

or adding `--no-daemon` to *Gradle*'s command line args as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40838127/1343979) doesn't really help (`System.in` is still an instance of `java.io.PipedInputStream`, while `System.out` and `System.err` are instances of `org.gradle.internal.io.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream`).

Is it possible to make *Gradle* stop messing with the terminal and allow the application being run to access it?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably assigning them wrongfully, because these both should be `ByteArrayOutputStream`. And probably they should not even be assigned in Gradle (the assignment of default values is redundant). Use `Exec` and then execute `java -jar fileName`, if you shouldn't get it working with `JavaExec`.