# Sign APK without putting keystore info in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, code-signing, apk-signing

I am trying to setup signing process so that keystore, password, and key password **are not** stored in the project's `build.gradle` file.

Currently I have the following in the `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my.keystore")
            storePassword "store_password"
            keyAlias "my_key_alias"
            keyPassword "key_password"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release            
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine but I **must not** put the values for the `storePassword`, and `keyPassword` in my repository. I would prefer to not put `storeFile` and `keyAlias` there either.

Is there a way to alter the `build.gradle` so that it will obtain passwords from some external source (like a file that resides on my computer only)?

And of course, the altered `build.gradle` should be usable on any other computer (even if the computer doesn't have access to passwords).

I am using Android Studio and in Mac OS X Maverics if it does matter.

Comment: "And of course, the altered build.gradle should be usable on any other computer (even if the computer doesn't have access to passwords)" -- if the data is not in `build.gradle`, you will have to have something other than `build.gradle`, whether that's an adjustment to environment variables (per one answer), a properties file (per another answer), or some other means. If you are unwilling to have things outside of `build.gradle`, then by definition all the signing information has to be *inside* `buid.gradle`.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right. I didn't tell I want to have anything strictly within the build.gradle, though. And I did tell that build.gradle could _obtain passwords from some external source (like a file that resides on my computer only_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

Comment: I've flagged as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle, on the basis of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311044/internal-link-only-answers-are-advisable/

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The nice thing about Groovy is that you can freely mix Java code, and it's pretty easy to read in a key/value file using `java.util.Properties`. Perhaps there's an even easier way using idiomatic Groovy, but Java is still pretty simple.

Create a `keystore.properties` file (in this example, in the root directory of your project next to `settings.gradle`, though you can put it wherever you like:

```
storePassword=...
keyPassword=...
keyAlias=...
storeFile=...
```

Add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        def propsFile = rootProject.file('keystore.properties')
        def configName = 'release'

        if (propsFile.exists() && android.signingConfigs.hasProperty(configName)) {
            def props = new Properties()
            props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
            android.signingConfigs[configName].storeFile = file(props['storeFile'])
            android.signingConfigs[configName].storePassword = props['storePassword']
            android.signingConfigs[configName].keyAlias = props['keyAlias']
            android.signingConfigs[configName].keyPassword = props['keyPassword']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the quotes from my keystore.properties

Comment: It doesn't generate the signed version for me with plugin version 0.9.+. What am I supposed to do with the signingConfigs block and buildTypes.release.signingConfig item? remove them?

Comment: Seems that setting storeFile to any valid value (e.g. ``storeFile file('AndroidManifest.xml')``) and then later overriding it causes the signing process to take place.

Comment: Building results in an error `Error:(24, 0) Could not find property 'android' on root project 'RootProjectName'` where line 24 is the one with the if-block. Adding `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to the root build.gradle also lets the build fail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Different from ferdy182, I can't generate an aligned apk. As [Xavier Ducrohet said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17607894/1819810), ZipAlign must happen _after_ signing. It solves my issue to put the above code in signingConfigs.release block. [Here](https://gist.github.com/KANGOD/43c7ce3e9efb1759e572) is code example.

Comment: @JacobTabak removing the quote from keystore.properties defo sorted my error problem. Thanks!

Comment: For windows and a relative path that traverses to the project's parent directory, I found I needed: android.signingConfigs[configName].storeFile = file(rootProject.projectDir.absolutePath + props['storeFile'])

Comment: This is a great solution, though kind of regretting not reading @JacobTabak 's comment first.

Comment: @PhilLab I had the same issue. I solved it by adding a check to ensure that android property exist. This is what I used `if (propsFile.exists() && project.hasProperty("android") && project.android.signingConfigs.hasProperty(configName))`

Comment: Does anyone know where exactly this goes in build.gradle, and in which build.gradle? If I stick it in the top-level build.gradle, I get the error "Could not get unknown property 'android' for root project". If I stick it in app/build.gradle, I get "could not find method allProjects()".

Comment: This doesn't work on year 2018. This must be deprecated? Kept throwing error that `Could not get unknown property 'android' for root project`

Comment: Tried and succeeded with this method in 2020, Android Studio 4.1 - the key was to put this answer in the app level gradle, instead of the project level gradle

Comment: Getting the error: "Keystore file '...' not found for signing config 'release'."

Comment: Update: Worked for me when I used "storeFile=clientkeystore" and placed the "clientkeystore" file under <project dir>/app folder.

Answer (score 150):

Alternatively, if you want to apply Scott Barta's answer in a way more similar to the auto generated gradle code, you can create a `keystore.properties` file in your project root folder:

```
storePassword=my.keystore
keyPassword=key_password
keyAlias=my_key_alias
storeFile=store_file
```

and modify your gradle code to:

```
// Load keystore
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties");
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

...

android{

    ...

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

You can store this properties file in the root of your module, in which case just omit `rootProject`, and you can also modify this code to have several sets of properties for different keystores and key aliases.

Comment: Works great. I used `if ( keystorePropertiesFile.exists() )` to make sure the file is present before trying to get the attributes and try to sign.

Comment: And don't forget to add `.txt` extension in the end of  `keystore.properties` file.

Comment: You shouldn't need a `.txt` extension on the `keystore.properties` file.

Comment: Looks like this info was added here - https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#secure-shared-keystore

Answer (score 43):

The easiest way is to create a `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file.

```
ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD=hunter2
ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD=hunter2
```

Then your `build.gradle` file can look like this:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('yourfile.keystore')
            storePassword ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias 'youralias'
            keyPassword ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should i gitignore ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?

Comment: The full instructions is also in react native documentation.

Comment: @vzhen no. since the file is not inside your project directory.

Comment: and don't quote those strings in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` regardless of the characters you use.

Comment: how is it secure?  gradle.properties can also be accessed.

Comment: `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` is your home directory, not your project directory `gradle.properties`, hence there's no way to push it to your repository. These are 2 separate files.

Answer (score 25):

**After reading a few links:**

http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/
https://www.thoughtworks.com/en-gb/insights/blog/signing-open-source-android-apps-without-disclosing-passwords

**Since you are using Mac OSX, you can use the Keychain Access to store your passwords.**

[image: How to add password in Keychain Access]

**Then in your gradle scripts:**

```
/* Get password from Mac OSX Keychain */
def getPassword(String currentUser, String keyChain) {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def stderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'security', '-q', 'find-generic-password', '-a', currentUser, '-gl', keyChain
        standardOutput = stdout
        errorOutput = stderr
        ignoreExitValue true
    }
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    (stderr.toString().trim() =~ /password: '(.*)'/)[0][1]
}
```

**Use like this:**

> getPassword(currentUser, "Android_Store_Password")

```
/* Plugins */
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

/* Variables */
ext.currentUser = System.getenv("USER")
ext.userHome = System.getProperty("user.home")
ext.keystorePath = 'KEY_STORE_PATH'

/* Signing Configs */
android {  
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(userHome + keystorePath + project.name)
            storePassword getPassword(currentUser, "ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias 'jaredburrows'
            keyPassword getPassword(currentUser, "ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: although your answer only applies to Mac OSX, I really like it! Note that the second link you provided contains a backup solution for other platforms, in case someone needs to implement multi-platform support.

Comment: Can you please provide the same solution for linux and windows as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Jared Burrows! Thought you'd like to know that now you can pass `-w` instead of `-g` and only the password will be output.

Answer (score 22):

This is how I do it. Use Environment Variables

```
  signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(System.getenv("KEYSTORE"))
        storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
        keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
        keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires system environments to be created for _each project_ on _each computer_. Otherwise I get following error `Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null'`

Comment: @Bobrovsky I know this question is answered, but you can use system environment variables or the gradle.properties file. You are probably wanting to use the gradle.properties file. You can use it for multiple projects.

Comment: this doesn't work on MacOSX unless you run Android Studio from the command-line.

Comment: I agree with all above. I have the same configuration and you cannot compile this in Android studio. You need to run from command line for this to work. I am looking for a better way, so that I dont have to comment these lines when I run in Android Studio.

Comment: @Bobrovsky : Does it work on windows?. Should we mention all these in system environments?

Comment: How to setup env in zshrc? 

I tried as below.. but unfortunately not throwing be some error
```
export KEYSTORE_PASS="password"
export ALIAS_NAME="password"
export ALIAS_PASS="password"
```
Error:

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storePassword".

Answer (score 20):

It is possible to take any existing Android Studio gradle project and build/sign it from the command line without editing any files. This makes it very nice for storing your project in version control while keeping your keys and passwords separate and not in your build.gradle file:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$KEYFILE -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$STORE_PASSWORD -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Also relevant: `android.injected.signing.v1-enabled` and `android.injected.signing.v2-enabled`. Source: https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/base/+/mirror-goog-studio-master-dev:build-system/builder-model/src/main/java/com/android/builder/model/AndroidProject.java;l=88

Answer (score 15):

For the ones looking to put their credentials in an external **JSON file** and read that from the gradle this is what I did:

my_project/credentials.json:

```
{
    "android": {
        "storeFile": "/path/to/acuity.jks",
        "storePassword": "your_store_password",
        "keyAlias": "your_android_alias",
        "keyPassword": "your_key_password"
    }
}
```

my_project/android/app/build.gradle

```
// ...
signingConfigs {
        release {

            def credsFilePath = file("../../credentials.json").toString()
            def credsFile = new File(credsFilePath, "").getText('UTF-8')
            def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(credsFile)
            storeFile file(json.android.storeFile)
            storePassword = json.android.storePassword
            keyAlias = json.android.keyAlias
            keyPassword = json.android.keyPassword
        }
        ...
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release //I added this
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

The reason I chose a `.json` file type, and not a `.properties` file type (as in the accepted answer), is because I wanted to also store other data (other custom properties I needed) to that same file (`my_project/credentials.json`), and still have gradle parse the signing information from within that file as well.

Comment: Seems like the best solution to me.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer use a file to controls which keystore to use to sign the APK that resides in the same root folder of project. When we using [vcs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) like [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)), could be a bad thing when we forget to add the properties file to ignore list. Because we will disclose our password to the world. The problems still persist.

Instead making properties file in the same directory within our project, we should make it outside. We make it outside by using gradle.properties file.

Here the steps:

1.Edit or create gradle.properties on your root project and add the following code, remember to edit the path with your own:

```
AndroidProject.signing=/your/path/androidproject.properties
```

2.Create androidproject.properties in /your/path/ and add the following code to it, don't forget to change /your/path/to/android.keystore to your keystore path:

```
STORE_FILE=/your/path/to/android.keystore  
STORE_PASSWORD=yourstorepassword  
KEY_ALIAS=yourkeyalias  
KEY_PASSWORD=yourkeypassword
```

3.In your app module build.gradle (not your project root build.gradle) add the following code if not exist or adjust to it:

```
signingConfigs {  
     release  
   }  
   buildTypes {  
   debug {  
     debuggable true  
   }  
   release {  
     minifyEnabled true  
     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
     signingConfig signingConfigs.release  
   }  
 }
```

4.Add the following code below the code in step 3:

```
if (project.hasProperty("AndroidProject.signing")  
     && new File(project.property("AndroidProject.signing").toString()).exists()) {  
     def Properties props = new Properties()  
     def propFile = new File(project.property("AndroidProject.signing").toString())  
     if(propFile.canRead()) {  
      props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))  
      if (props!=null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&  
         props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {  
         android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])  
         android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']  
         android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']  
         android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']  
      } else {  
         println 'androidproject.properties found but some entries are missing'  
         android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null  
      }  
     } else {  
            println 'androidproject.properties file not found'  
          android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null  
     }  
   }
```

This code will search for AndroidProject.signing property in **gradle.properties** from *step 1*. If the property found, it will translate property value as file path which pointing to androidproject.properties that we create in *step 2*. Then all the property value from it will be used as signing configuration for our build.gradle.

Now we don't need to worry again of risk of exposing our keystore password.

Read more at [Signing Android apk without putting keystore info in build.gradle](http://belajarotodidak.blogspot.co.id/2015/11/signing-android-apk-without-putting.html)

Comment: This workes fine for me. just to know why they are using   storeFile file(System.getenv("KEYSTORE"))

Answer (score 8):

This question has received many valid answers, but I wanted to share my code which may be useful for **library maintainers**, because it **leaves the original `build.gradle` quite clean**.

I add a folder to the module directory which I `gitignore`. It looks like this:

```
/signing
    /keystore.jks
    /signing.gradle
    /signing.properties
```

`keystore.jks` and `signing.properties` should be self explanatory. And `signing.gradle` looks like this:

```
def propsFile = file('signing/signing.properties')
def buildType = "release"

if (!propsFile.exists()) throw new IllegalStateException("signing/signing.properties file missing")

def props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))

def keystoreFile = file("signing/keystore.jks")
if (!keystoreFile.exists()) throw new IllegalStateException("signing/keystore.jks file missing")

android.signingConfigs.create(buildType, {
    storeFile = keystoreFile
    storePassword = props['storePassword']
    keyAlias = props['keyAlias']
    keyPassword = props['keyPassword']
})

android.buildTypes[buildType].signingConfig = android.signingConfigs[buildType]
```

And the original `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
if (project.file('signing/signing.gradle').exists()) {
    apply from: 'signing/signing.gradle'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation ...
}
```

As you can see, you don't have to specify the buildTypes at all, if user has access to a valid `signing` directory, he just puts it in the module and he can build a valid signed release application, otherwise it just works for him like it would normally do.

Comment: I really like this solution. Note however, `apply from` should come after the `android` block

Answer (score 5):

Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33218300/1673761 with some improvements

### Pros

- keystore properties (file name, alias, passwords) are stored outside of git
- Debug mode still works even if we don't have a keystore file or keystore.properties
- The keystore and its properties are in the root folder side by side

### In the root of your project (or in `android` folder for React Native):

- Add your generated keystore file ie: `app.keystore`
- create a file named `keystore.properties`
- Add these two files to `.gitignore`

### In `keystore.properties` add

```
STORE_FILE=app.keystore
KEY_ALIAS=app_alias
STORE_PASSWORD=your_password
KEY_PASSWORD=your_password
```

### In `app/build.gradle` add

```
// Load keystore
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
try {
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties");
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
} catch(IOException e) {
    // We don't have release keys, ignoring
}

...

android {
  ...
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      if (keystoreProperties['STORE_FILE']) {
        storeFile rootProject.file(keystoreProperties['STORE_FILE'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['STORE_PASSWORD']
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['KEY_ALIAS']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['KEY_PASSWORD']
      }
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
}
```

PS: Edits to improve the groovy logic are welcome

Comment: I just had to rebuild the project before Android Studio stopped complaining.

Comment: how is it safe ? Credentials can be read from keystore.properties

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using CI tools storing your credentials in cleartext in a text file is a bad idea, even if the file is not under version control.

I know this is common practice (even [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#secure-shared-keystore) mention it) but you wouldn't even think of storing the password of your personal email in a textfile, why would you do it with your app(s)?

My approach is to have a simple **command that queries both passwords** and builds the release while keeping my build.gradle as clean as possible. I.e.:

```
Key store password:
Key password:
```

I had a look at other answers but they either *a)* store credentials as cleartext *b)* didn't work or *c)* overcomplicate stuff.

---

1. Add this signing config to build.gradle:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       signingConfigs {
           release {
               storeFile file(findProperty('keystore_path') ?: 'default path')
               storePassword findProperty('keystore_pw')
               keyAlias findProperty('key_alias')
               keyPassword findProperty('key_pw')
           }
       }
       ...

       buildTypes {
           release {
               ...
               signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Run this command in the project dir (edit `/PATH/TO/KEYSTORE.jks` and `KEY_ALIAS`):

   ```
   echo -n Key store password: && read -s storepw && echo && \
   echo -n Key password: && read -s keypw && echo && \
   ./gradlew assembleRelease -Pkeystore_path='/PATH/TO/KEYSTORE.jks' -Pkeystore_pw=$storepw -Pkey_alias='KEY_ALIAS' -Pkey_pw=$keypw
   ```

Answer (score 1):

### In `keystore.properties

```
    STORE_FILE = app.keystore
    KEY_ALIAS = app_alias
    STORE_PASSWORD = your_password
    KEY_PASSWORD = your_password
```

### In `app/build.gradle.kts` add

```
...

android {
  ...
  signingConfigs {
    create("release") {
    // Load keystore
    val keystoreProperties = Properties().apply{
        load(File("keystore.properties").reader())
    }
    storeFile = File(keystoreProperties.getProperty("STORE_FILE"))
    storePassword = keystoreProperties.getProperty("STORE_PASSWORD")
    keyAlias = keystoreProperties.getProperty("KEY_ALIAS")
    keyPassword= keystoreProperties.getProperty("KEY_PASSWORD")
   }
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request passwords from the command line:

```
...

signingConfigs {
  if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any {it.contains('Release') }) {
    release {
      storeFile file("your.keystore")
      storePassword new String(System.console().readPassword("\n\$ Enter keystore password: "))
      keyAlias "key-alias"
      keyPassword new String(System.console().readPassword("\n\$ Enter keys password: "))
    } 
  } else {
    //Here be dragons: unreachable else-branch forces Gradle to create
    //install...Release tasks.
    release {
      keyAlias 'dummy'
      keyPassword 'dummy'
      storeFile file('dummy')
      storePassword 'dummy'
    } 
  }
}

...

buildTypes {
  release {

    ...

    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }

  ...
}

...
```

This answer previously appeared: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33765572/3664487

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10250960)

Comment: @mkobit, this is a link to content on Stack Overflow! I could, of course, copy and paste the linked content, but that leads to duplicate content. Thus, I assume, and correct me if I am wrong, posting a link is the best solution. Any argument that "the linked page changes" should be dismissed, on the basis that the content here could change too.

I strong recommend against your solution to delete! Because the linked content provides an excellent solution.

Comment: Well, I think the problem is that this is still a "link-only" answer. I think the solution is to post it as a comment, flag the question as a duplicate, or write a new answer here that addresses the problem.

Comment: "Link-only" answers should be encouraged in some instances. Nevertheless, I have followed your advice and duplicated content. (Duplicated content is clearly problematic, because some content might be updated, whereas the remaining content might not be.)

Comment: Indeed, I have just updated the answer and duplicate content is causing problems! If there's a policy against link-only answers, then it should be adapted to consider such corner cases.

Comment: I may have a different opinion than others. If you think it warrants further discussion I recommend you make a post on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I've started a discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311044/internal-link-only-answers-are-advisable

Answer (score 0):

My password contained a special character which dollar sign **$** and I had to escape that in gradle.properties file. After that, signing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is another answer for [Kotlin build scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts) different from [Anand Damodaran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68944033/8583692).

It tries to read from *local.properties* file, falling back to the OS environment variables. It can be especially useful in CIs like GitHub Actions (you can create environment secrets in your repository settings).

Note that I'm using Kotlin 1.6.10 and Gradle 7.4.2 and Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 7.0.4.

```kotlin
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties
// ...

val environment = System.getenv()
fun getLocalProperty(key: String) = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty(key)
fun String.toFile() = File(this)

android {
    signingConfigs {
        create("MySigningConfig") {
            keyAlias = getLocalProperty("signing.keyAlias") ?: environment["SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS"] ?: error("Error!")
            storeFile = (getLocalProperty("signing.storeFile") ?: environment["SIGNING_STORE_FILE"] ?: error("Error!")).toFile()
            keyPassword = getLocalProperty("signing.keyPassword") ?: environment["SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD"] ?: error("Error!")
            storePassword = getLocalProperty("signing.storePassword") ?: environment["SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD"] ?: error("Error!")
            enableV1Signing = true
            enableV2Signing = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs["MySigningConfig"]
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
}
```

As said, you can either have a *local.properties* file at the root of your project with values for the properties:

```
signing.keyAlias=My key
signing.keyPassword=zyxwvuts
signing.storePassword=abcdefgh
signing.storeFile=C\:\\Users\\Mahozad\\keystore.jks
```

... or you can set/create environment variables on your OS; for example to create an environment variable called `SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS` run:

- Windows Command Prompt: `setx SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS "My key"`
- Linux Terminal: `export SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS="My key"`