# Android Gradle - load signing config from external file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In Gradle for Android it seems to be commons practice to define your signing config for release build like this:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }

        myConfig {
            storeFile file("other.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        foo {
            debuggable true
            jniDebugBuild true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
        }
    }
}
```

Thing is, I want to keep my build.gradle file in version control and don't have a good feeling having the password for my keystore (which is the same I use for other stuff, stupid, I know) on some git server.

Is there a way to load the signingConfig from an external file from somewhere on my hard drive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign APK without putting keystore info in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562189/sign-apk-without-putting-keystore-info-in-build-gradle)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I use something like this.

I have a `signing.properties` in my app root folder.

```
STORE_FILE=xxxx
STORE_PASSWORD=xxx
KEY_ALIAS=xxx
KEY_PASSWORD=xxx
```

**This file is not on under version control.**
Of course you can change folder.

Then in your `build.gradle` you can use something like this:

```
 android {

        signingConfigs {
            release
        }

        buildTypes {
                release {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                }     
        }
    }

    def Properties props = new Properties()
    def propFile = file('../signing.properties')
    if (propFile.canRead()){
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

        if (props!=null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
                props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {

            android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
            android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
            android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
            android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
        } else {
            android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
        }
    }else {
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
```

If you change the folder, you have to change this line:

```
 def propFile = file('../signing.properties')
```

Comment: I'm trying the same, but instead of hard coding the path I'm taking path from `local.properties` it can read the file but showing `Error:(33, 0) Malformed \uxxxx encoding.` in the line `properties.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))` I even hard coded the path and tried but of no use. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

### For Kotlin Script (build.gradle.kts)

Put a file *signing.properties* where the module specific *build.gradle.kts* is found. Don't forget to add it to your *.gitignore* file!

**signing.properties**

```
storeFilePath=/home/willi/example.keystore
storePassword=secret
keyPassword=secret
keyAlias=myReleaseSigningKey
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
android {
    // ...
    signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            val properties = Properties().apply {
                load(File("signing.properties").reader())
            }
            storeFile = File(properties.getProperty("storeFilePath"))
            storePassword = properties.getProperty("storePassword")
            keyPassword = properties.getProperty("keyPassword")
            keyAlias = properties.getProperty("keyAlias")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using hardcoded keyAlias, not the one in properties file

Comment: This sample requires `import java.util.Properties`

Answer (score 3):

### For Groovy (build.gradle)

Put a file *signing.properties* where the module specific *build.gradle* is found. Don't forget to add it to your *.gitignore* file!

**signing.properties**

```
storeFilePath=/home/willi/example.keystore
storePassword=secret
keyPassword=secret
keyAlias=myReleaseSigningKey
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    // ...
    signingConfigs{
        release {
            def props = new Properties()

            def fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file('../signing.properties'))
            props.load(fileInputStream)
            fileInputStream.close()

            storeFile = file(props['storeFilePath'])
            storePassword = props['storePassword']
            keyAlias = props['keyAlias']
            keyPassword = props['keyPassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move your sensitive details to a separate signing file and have gradle load those in.

[Here's a good article on how to do it](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/)