# Use a local.properties field when declaring a buildConfigField

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a `build.gradle` and a `local.properties` file.  I want to declare a value in `local.properties`, which isn't checked in to version control, to use in `build.gradle`.

I have the `buildConfigField` working with:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "TEST", "test"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately though, this causes an error:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "TEST", local.properties.get("test")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find code to steal here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562189/sign-apk-without-putting-keystore-info-in-build-gradle/20573171#20573171

Answer (score 13):

It can be achieved like:

```
def getProps(String propName) {
  def propsFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
  if (propsFile.exists()) {
    def props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
    return props[propName]
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

in your buildTypes block:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "TEST", getProps("test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to throw an Exception if the file or the propName isn't found, rather than silently returning null/empty string.