# Should gradle.properties be in gitignore for a react native project to hide release password?

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, gitignore

I'm working on a react native app on windows. To be able to [generate a signed release apk](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/signed-apk-android.html) I've added `MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=***` and `MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=***` to my `/projectname/android/gradle.properties` file ([Like it says so here](http://10minbasics.com/react-native-could-not-find-property-myapp_release_store_file/)). Now I wonder if I should add the file to gitignore to prevent it from being uploaded to github, or is there a way to store the password in a different file?

Comment: Check this link in the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android-gradle/5249/configure-signing-settings#t=201702081442045666847 There are a lot of way to handle the file which stores the password.

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution for storing the passwords in a separate file here: [Sign APK without putting keystore info in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562189/sign-apk-without-putting-keystore-info-in-build-gradle/33218300#33218300)

In build.gradle add:

```
// Load keystore
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystores/release.keystore.properties");
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
```

And a bit further down:

```
signingConfigs { 
    release { 
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD']
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD']
    }
}
```

And then add `release.keystore.properties` to the `.gitignore` file defined like so:

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=x
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=y
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=z
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=t
```

(Sorry for answering my own question, I hate doing that..)

Comment: So what is the content inside `keystores/release.keystore.properties` ?  

Is it these?
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=myapp-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=myapp-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=password
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=password

Answer (score 0):

You can add that information to your super gradle.properties file on `${HOME}/.gradle/gradle.properties` and it should be ready for you.

You can also rename those properties on the `app/build.gradle` and use different ones for different projects if required.

For example, my project FOO has

```
112         release {
113             storeFile file(FOO_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
114             storePassword FOO_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
115             keyAlias FOO_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
116             keyPassword FOO_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
117         }
```

And on my `${HOME}/.gradle/gradle.properties` I have:

```
1 FOO_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=foo-release-key.keystore
2 FOO_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=foo.android
3 FOO_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=******************
4 FOO_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=***************
```

Comment: But the issue with this is that when you use windows ´${HOME}/.gradle/gradle.properties´ doesn't seem to exist (described also on the linked blogpost).

Answer (score 0):

You can create `${HOME}/.gradle/gradle.properties`, as it doesn't exist by default, at least on Windows.

Put the key there exactly as you would in your project `gradle.properties`. You can see the order of precedence [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties).