# Gradle - Different configs for release and debug don't work

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to set up Gradle to have different settings for release and debug builds.

Use case: developers do not need the signing file and configs to build a debug version.

**But gradle refuses to sync/build a `debug` version because a file is missing** (`def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")` - but those settings are for release build only.

What am I doing wrong?

```
...

android {

    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfigs {

                def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

                // Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
                def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

                // Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
                keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']

            }
        }
        debug {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: Probably file not found? You can try following my answer to secure your keystore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562189/sign-apk-without-putting-keystore-info-in-build-gradle/38046932#38046932

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whole gradle file is evaluated when building. so it will throw error. Incase of debug I think gradle auto sign the apk with the android debug keystore

Either comment the signing for release

**or**

provide a properties file with dummy content so that gradle build works incase of debug

Comment: That..a bit disturbing. thanks for the help :) Why would gradle do that? what the point of evaluating settings I do not currently need?

Comment: it is basically a script so thats why I think it evaluate/run line by line

Answer (score 1):

You can always out some checking in plain Java like :

```
File keystorePropertiesFile = new File(distrDir, fileName)
  if (!keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
     println "DEBUG message, properties set not from production file"
     // throw new GradleException('Also you can interrupt everything')
  } else {
     println "Do your file loading here..."
 }
```