# Shall I include build.gradle file in a public GitHub repository?

Tags: android, git, github, gradle

The `build.gradle (app)` file contains the app's `keystore` location and password. So I wonder, if I should include those in a public GitHub repository or not?

My guess would be 'no', and if so, how might I go about this problem? Can I somehow censor it or should I simply not include the files in the commits?

If I should leave them from the commit, how can I solve the problem with pulling the project because the file would be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `build.gradle` file there is all the configuration for your android project.
**Without this file it is impossible to build the project**.

Then yes, you have to include it in the git repo.

But you can move all the sensitive data like [keystore location and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562189/sign-apk-without-putting-keystore-info-in-build-gradle), out of `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-shared-keystore) help you and also write the files or folders that you don't want to push in your remote repository in **.gitignore** file.for example, look at this [link](https://gist.github.com/iainconnor/8605514)