# Android Studio is not generating zip aligned apk

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2

My sdk is well updated and build-tools version installed is 22.0.1

```
Build > Generate Signed Apk
```

I only get app-release-unaligned.apk in (app/build/outputs/apk/)

I have already googled and tried:

1. Copy Pasting "zipalign.exe" from build-tools folder to : (i) sdk/tools/ (ii) sdk/platform-tools/
2. Adding "zipAlignEnabled true" under buildTypes in build.gradle
3. [Gradle zipAlign task not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604448/gradle-zipalign-task-not-working)

Please help solve this issue, I want to zipalign using Android Studio.

This is my first app i am trying to publish !!!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is pretty easy to generate the signed apk file with Android Studio.

Here are the steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had te same issue. The aligned apk is generated on app/ folder, not in output/ folder.

Comment: The confusion is, there are two .apks generated one is not aligned another is (in a different folder as pictured).

Comment: @yushulx Not so straight-forward with me. I do not see that icon or the `apk` upfront as you've shown. Did not create the project from scratch in `AndroidStudio`, had to import it from `Eclipse` - could that be why? I will continue looking, but if you know off-hand where this zipaligned `apk` is in my scenario, please reply. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work, app-release.apk is still not zip-aligned

Answer (score 0):

You probably *are* generating it, but the release `.apk` file is placed in a different directory from the other `.apk` files.

On my system, for an app called TheApp, `.apk` files are usually placed in the `build/outputs/apk` directory:

```
TheApp/build/outputs/apk/TheApp-debug.apk
TheApp/build/outputs/apk/TheApp-debug-unaligned.apk
TheApp/build/outputs/apk/TheApp-release-unaligned.apk
```

but the aligned release `.apk` file is placed directly in the app's root directory :

```
TheApp/TheApp-release.apk
```

(This was already answered by @yushulx but I hope this shorter answer is clearer).