# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:zipalignDebug'. > when I run my app on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debian

I've installed Debian 8 and I installed Android Studio without problem, but when I run my application, created when I had Android Studio on Ubuntu 15.04, I've this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:zipalignDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/phate/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/zipalign'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

what kind of error is this? How I can resolve?

Thank you at all,
Dennis

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604448/gradle-zipalign-task-not-working

Comment: I think something with your path SDK.

Comment: earlier today I had never seen this zipAlign... why now I have this error. I don't understand what is. It's not a serious app it is for study android development

Answer (score 4):

I know that this question is 4 months old, but I'm putting the answer here so that it may help someone else.
Before the actual error, I got something like this:

> error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So the following command helped me, I hope it helps you too.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```