# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:zipalignDebug'.

Tags: android, android-studio, zipalign

I tried to run one of my old projects in android studio & I am getting the following error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:zipalignDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/newaj/Android/build-tools/25.0.0/zipalign''
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/35164025/5237917

Comment: clean and build your project if not work than do goto  File/Invalidate caches & Restart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:zipalignDebug'. > when I run my app on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548170/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appzipaligndebug-when-i-run-my-app-on-and)

Comment: @HemantParmar, Still the same result.

Comment: @KulsDroid, Not worked here. Still getting the error.